# How to add label and avoid covered each other

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

[image]

In `ggplot2::facet_wrap`, I want to add labels `inc` ,code `geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(inc,0.1)),hjust=2,vjust=12)` can work, but the labels covered each other. How to adjust the label  position for label `inc`? thanks!

As attached image, I want to remove the label `75%` of category  B into  red column

```
library(tidyverse)
plot_data <- data.frame(category=c('A','A','B','B'),
                        period=c('2022','2023','2022','2023'),
                        sales=c(10,12,0.2,0.35))

plot_data %>% group_by(category) %>% mutate(inc = sales/lag(sales)-1) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=category,y=sales,fill=period))+geom_col(position=position_dodge(0.8))+
  geom_text(aes(label = sales),position = position_dodge2(0.8))+
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(inc,0.1)),hjust=2,vjust=12)+
  facet_wrap(~ category,scales="free")
```

Comment: Take a look at the [ggrepel](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/vignettes/ggrepel.html) package.

Comment: The issue is that you are using `hjust` and `vjust` to position your labels. Both arguments are meant to specify the alignment and even if we mis-use them occasionally to add some padding, when you want to shift or nudge your labels by larger amounts there are better options. Perhaps you could clarify where you want to position the labels showing the percentage increase?

Comment: @stefan Thanks, i have edited the post .Could you help to take a look ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already mentioned in my comment, the issue is that you use `hjust` and `vjust` to move your labels. Both arguments are meant to specify the alignment of the label and even if we mis-use them occasionally to add some padding, when you want to shift or nudge your labels by larger amounts there are better options.

However, IMHO in your case the easiest approach would be to use only one label, i.e. `paste` both parts of the label together and add a linebreak. Additionally I simply moved the label inside the bars and added some padding via `vjust`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

plot_data %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  mutate(
    inc = lead(sales) / sales - 1,
    label = if_else(
      !is.na(inc),
      paste0(sales, "\n", scales::percent(inc, 0.1)),
      paste0(sales, "\n", "")
    )
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = category, y = sales, fill = period)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(0.8)) +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      label = label
    ),
    position = position_dodge(0.8),
    vjust = 1.1
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~category, scales = "free")
```

[image]

But if you insist on having the `sales` label vertically centered on the top of the bar you do so as well with some fiddling with `vjust`, e.g. `vjust=.825` seems to do the job:

```r
plot_data %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  mutate(
    inc = lead(sales) / sales - 1,
    label = if_else(
      !is.na(inc),
      paste0(sales, "\n", scales::percent(inc, 0.1)),
      paste0(sales, "\n", "")
    )
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = category, y = sales, fill = period)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(0.8)) +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      label = label, group = period
    ),
    position = position_dodge(0.8),
    vjust = .825
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~category, scales = "free")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks ,  if delete  [group = period] , it seems the same ,what's the purpose ?

Comment: Aw. Yeah. Not needed. The `geom_text` inherits the right grouping from `fill`. Just made an edit and removed it.